# Why does Rich Hickey think VMs, not OSes, are the platforms of the future?

Tags: clojure, jvm

On the [Why Clojure?](https://clojure.org/about/rationale) Rich Hickey (assumedly) makes the claim that "VMs, not OSes, are the platforms of the future" citing type systems, libraries abstracting OSes, memory managment and Bytecode + JIT compilation. I understand all these things come with a VM platform, but they've been around for 25 years. What will make OS and hardware abstraction more desirable in the future, especially when weighed against the performance cost of this abstraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why Clojure? is answering the self-posed question- why did I write another programming language?- in the context of the computing ecosystem of 2006-2007, when Clojure was invented. Very different world back then.

When viewed in a modern context, languages like Go and Rust can be seen as counter-arguments to a VMs-over-OSes claim- providing usability, the leverage of new abstractions, and efficiency, in a single no-VM, multi-OS toolchain.

That said, evidence of the success of VM abstractions- LLVM, JSVM, the mobile VMs, beyond the continued dominance of the JVM- in the 10+ years since Clojure was invented is overwhelming. The VM abstraction allows enormous engineering armies to focus on achieving OS-like performance and efficiency results underneath the abstraction. Continuing efforts like serverless and unikernels even further abstract away the OS, while achieving even better performance or efficiency results.

With a modern eye, and from a language designer's perspective, the story in Why Clojure? is a little dated, and specific counter-arguments to the core claim are easy to find. However, when viewed with the perspective of history, one has to say Rich got it pretty much right.